# Increasing width of UISearchDisplayController PopOver Results

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, uikit, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have an iPad app that has a UISearchBar in its navigation bar.  When I enter text in the search bar the results are automatically displayed in a UIPopOverController.  That's great except the popover's default size is not wide enough for my needs.  Is there a way to set its width?

Apple has done this themselves with Safari's search bar.  The popover that displays search results is a good bit wider than the default and they have removed the "Results" title from the popover.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to set the `contentSizeForViewInPopover` property of the `UIViewController` that's being displayed in the popover.  I'm not sure how you get to that if it's all automagically happening behind the scenes.